# Which JVM based script language use "when" as branch control keyword (instead of "if")?

Tags: programming-languages, indentation, jvm-languages

I saw a presentation with a code-snippet with "when" instead of "if".
The code saw like a JVM-based scripting language, used indentation instead of "{}"
and not each line was finished with ';'

Could you give me a clue, which language it could be?

Comment: both scala and groovy use `if`

Comment: Jython is indentation based but seems to use only `if`

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://github.com/Frege/frege.

Comment: @gefei scala is not a script language

Comment: @pedrofurla: thank you, but I'm affraid it wasn't. A functional language should be easy to recognise on (((((such code))))), shouldn't it? :-)

Comment: Not the ones from the Haskell family.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby had the case-when statements. My guess would be "JRuby".

```
case x
when User === x 
    puts "Constant"
when "User" === x
    puts "string"
else 
    puts "nothing"
end
```